# Default select option in angular2 not working

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu, angular-ngmodel

An application developed in `angular2` on which I have different food categories, If I pick some category (e.g: salads..) and in that page I want to add a specific food a modal popped up with some fields to add infos about the food, among those fields there is a `dropdown-list` with different categories, what I want is that the category that i'm already on it (was picked) would appear as selected by default.

Here is a `category` page:

[image]

clicking on the `button` on the `top-right` will pop that modal:

[image]

I want that that category will be selected by default.

Here what I've done but did not work:

`Add item modal` HTML part :

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="category">{{'category' | translate}}</label>
    <select
      id="category"
      class="form-control"
      formControlName="select"
      [ngModel]="currentCategory"
    >
      <option [value]="category.id" *ngFor="let category of categories">
        {{category.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
```

And here is its `TS` part:

```
    export class AddItemModalComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  // @Input() currentCategory: any;
  @Input() isAdvanced:      boolean;

  public currentCategory:       any;
  public  currentCurrency:      string;
  public  itemForm:             FormGroup;
  public  categories:           Category[];
  public  deactivated:          boolean = true;

  private pictureData:          any;
  private categoryId:           string;
  private pictureUploaded:      boolean;
  private isCategoriesLastPage: boolean;
  private pageNumber:           number = 0;


  constructor(
    private router:          UIRouter,
    private formBuilder:     FormBuilder,
    private pageService:     PageService,
    private itemService:     ItemService,
    public  activeModal:     NgbActiveModal,
    private uploadService:   LcUploadService,
    private categoryService: CategoryService
  ) {
    this.categoryId      = this.router.stateService.params['category'];
    this.categoryService.getCategory(this.categoryId).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.currentCategory = data.name;
        console.log(this.currentCategory)
      },
      error => console.log('Could not load category.')
    );
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.itemForm        = this.formBuilder.group({
      file:               new FormControl(''),
      item_type:          new FormControl(''),
      internal_reference: new FormControl(''),
      name:               new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      price:              new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      select:             new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      tax:                new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(REGEX.ONLY_POSITIVE)
      ])),
      description:        new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.minLength(7),
        Validators.maxLength(512)
      ]))
    });

  AddItem(): void {
    let newItem, formValue;
    if (this.itemForm.dirty && this.itemForm.valid) {
      formValue = this.itemForm.value;
      newItem = {
        tax:         formValue.tax,
        name:        formValue.name,
        price:       formValue.price,
        category_id: formValue.select,
        item_type:   formValue.item_type,
        description: formValue.description,
        picture:     this.pictureData.public_id
      };
      this.itemService.addItem(newItem).subscribe(
        (data: any): void => this.activeModal.close(data),
        (error: Response): void => console.log('Could not add item', error.json())
      );
    }
  }
}
```

It brings it in console but I do not know why it doesnt affect it to the `dropdown-list`

And here is the `TS` function of the opening modal button :

```
openAddItemDialog(): void {
    const modalRef: NgbModalRef           = this.modalService.open(
      AddItemModalComponent,
      {size: 'lg'}
    );
    modalRef.componentInstance.category   = this.breadcrumb;
    modalRef.componentInstance.isAdvanced = this.page.advanced;
    modalRef.result.then(
      (result: any): any => {
        if (this.categoryId === result.category.id) {
          this.items.unshift(result);
        }
      },
      (reason: any): void => console.log('Rejected!')
    );
  }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign the default value to `currentCategory`.
`[selected]` is not supported with `[ngModel]`

**Hint:** If you use `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]`, you can assign an object

```
[ngValue]="category"
```

The value assigned to `[ngModel]="..."` has to exactly match the value assigned to `[value]="..." or [ngValue]="..."`. You can display any value you want in {{category.name}]

If you use `[ngValue]` with an object or array, it's not enough when the value assigned to `[ngModel]` has the same properties with the same values. It needs to be the **same instance**.

Comment: but it is already assigned `this.currentCategory = data.name;` , in `data` you'll find categories' objects.. 
**PS** :  about the `[selected]` I was testing it is not a part of the code ..

Comment: So `currentCategory` contains the `category.id` you want to have selected by default?

Comment: no it contains the names of the categories .. I want those names on the dropdown-list

Comment: The value assigned to `[ngModel]="..."` has to exactly match the value assigned to `[value]="..."` or `[ngValue]="..."`. You can display any value you want in `<option ...>{{category.name}]</option>`.

Comment: Glad to hear :) Done.